# Не работает @media на сайте

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, media

У меня не работает @media для оптимизации сайта под телефон. Обыскал весь интернет, но ничего не нашел, что бы заработало. Может кто знает. Вот код: `https://jsfiddle.net/f9kx0m6h/2/`. Если хотите скачать: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dKgE04ac-gDF2LIJ2AnjhMTPZMZgR4tZ`. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Игорь, код надо приводить прямо в вопросе, а не ссылками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправленный кусок:
`@media (max-width: 1000px) { .code { float: right; width: 50px; } }`

Внимательней смотрите что пишете. ;)

1. `max-width: 10000px` - вы где такие экраны увидели?
2. `width: 50` не указаны единицы измерения